# Need help constructing a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I've a model that has a nested model of skills. Its a common has_many example. Elastic search is indexing the skills as an array of strings.

My question is, I am attempting to match on those skills by way of two different inputs.
Required skills and bonus skills.

So if I have two query terms one for required and one for bonus, I want to query the skills attribute with required input, if none found, query with the bonus input.

I'm using elasticsearch-rails gem. Didn't think I needed to post any code as this is more theory.
UPDATE

```
class Profile
  has_many :skills
...
end
class Skill
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

Mappings

```
settings index: { number_of_shards: 1, number_of_replicas: 0 } do
  ...
  mapping dynamic: 'false' do
    indexes :skills, analyzer: 'keyword'
  end
  ...
end
```

Overriden as_json

```
def as_indexed_json(options={})
  hash = self.as_json(
    include: {location: { methods: [:coordinates], only: [:coordinates]    },
              locations_of_interest: { methods: [:coordinates], only: [:coordinates]}
             })
  hash['skills'] = self.skills.map(&:name)
  hash['interests'] = self.interests.map(&:name)
  hash
end
```

I guess in essence i'm looking to perform the reverse of a multi_match on multiple fields and boosting one but instead searching one field with multiple inputs (required and bonus) and depending no the results of required search with bonus input. Does this makes things more clear?

This is my query so far, first attempt.

```
        if options[:required_skills].present? && options[:bonus_skills].present?
          bool do
            must do
              term skills: options[:required_skills]
            end
            should do
              term skills: options[:bonus_skills]
            end
          end
        end
```

Comment: I'm not clear on your data structure. What model has_many of what model? Are you trying to query the former or the latter? Its better to include at least the basic `has_many` code so we know what models/tables to talk about.

Comment: apologies, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SkillContainer < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :skill_links, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :skill_container
  has_many :skills, through: :skill_links

  has_many 
end

##################################
  create_table :skill_link do |t|
    t.references :skill
    t.references :skill_container
    t.boolean :required
    t.boolean :bonus
  end
##################################
class SkillLink
  belongs_to :skill_container
  belongs_to :skill

  scope :required, -> {
    where(required: true)
  }

  scope :bonus, -> {
    where(bonus: true)
  }
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skill_links, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :skill
  has_many :skills, through: :skill_links

end

#required skills from any skill container
SkillContainer.last.skills.merge(SkillLink.required)

#bonus skills from any skill container
SkillContainer.last.skills.merge(SkillLink.bonus)
```

scopes can be combined with your elastic search